# Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity' while trying to pull SID

Tags: powershell

I have the following:

```
foreach ($item in $tmpList){
$tmpID = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $server -Identity $item.Name | Select-Object SID | Select-Object -First 1

if (!$tmpID) { #somecode }
else{ $tmpSurname = Get-ADUser -Server $server  -Identity $tmpID -Properties Surname }
```

Unfortunately the code keeps giving me: **Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.**

I have checked the `$tmpID` manually by running the code by itself and it does grab a value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SID` the most asked question in the universe

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter instead of the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter. See the linked duplicate for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).SomeProperty`